# Next_permutation and efficiency

Tags: c++, stl

Is it more efficient to begin with a possibly random ordering of objects in a range, using next_permutation to step through all greater permutations, followed by stepping down, beginning again with the original ordering, using prev_permutation to reach the last.

Or, to sort the range before permuting, then to use only next_permutation to step through all of them?

Comment: add `permutation` here...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`next_permutation` will step through **all** permutations, not only through *greater* permutations. No need to revert and use `prev_permutation`, and certainly no need to sort.

You only need take care of the fact that `next_permutation` will return `false` once it “rolls over” into the lexicographically lowest permutation so you need to keep track of the number of the current permutation to know when to stop.

That is, the following will iterate through all possible permutations of a range, no matter how the starting range looks like.

```
size_t const num_permutations = multinomial_coefficient(range);

for (size_t i = 0; i < num_permutations; ++i) {
    next_permutation(range.begin(), range.end());
    // use permutation.
}
```

Where `multinomial_coefficient` is the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient#Multinomial_coefficients) of the number of distinct elements in the range. In the simple case where all elements are distinct, this is equivalent to *N*!, the factorial of the number of elements.

Comment: Thank you, the few examples I found would start with a basically sorted range then walk all the way up to the false and stop.  I was unable to find one that directly said yeah, rolls over, and keeps going.

Comment: `fact(range.size())` will exceed size_t for surprising small number of elements.

Comment: @René That is correct, and in fact my solution will only work for small ranges for that matter. That said, enumerating all permutations will *also* only work in practice for small ranges (albeit somewhat bigger ranges, granted).

Comment: @Konrad: I agree with you. Maybe I should have pointed out to @drb.

Comment: Note that this is incorrect if there can be duplicate elements in the range (next_permutation handles this correctly, but you can't determine the number of permutations from just the size of the range).  The OP's idea of running next_permutation one way and then prev_permutation the other is a good one; just have to make sure to properly handle the last and first permutations so they're each processed exactly once.

Comment: From what I've read, this use of `fact` will be wrong anyway, if there are duplicate items in the range, since `next_permutation` apparently handles that by not producing duplicate permutations.

Comment: @RobI Damn, you’re right, of course – thanks for pointing this out. For repetition you need the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_coefficient#Multinomial_coefficients). I’ll update the answer with more details if I find the time.

Comment: If one's going to enumerate all permutations, isn't sort basically free compared to the total cost?

Comment: @avmohan It’s not a large cost but it’s still unnecessary and certainly not free. Of course for big enough ranges it would be negligible. But “big enough” ranges are too big to practically enumerate all their permutations anyway.

Answer (score 2):

To get *all* permutations, start with a sorted range, then

```
do
{
  // something
} while(next_permutation(range.begin(), range.end());
```

It stops, when range is sorted again. The process is O(n!).

When you start with randomized range, you will miss some permutations.

Answer (score -1):

There's no difference at all, the algorithm doesn't reuse previous results so there's no need to sort beforehand.

Comment: curious about the truthfulness of this claim.

Comment: @lccarrasco #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>    // std::next_permutation, std::sort
using namespace std; 

int main () {
  int myints[] = {3,2,1};

  //std::sort (myints,myints+3);
  
  
  std::cout << "The 3! possible permutations with 3 elements:\n";
  do {
    std::cout << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';
  } while ( std::next_permutation(myints,myints+3) );

  std::cout << "After loop: " << myints[0] << ' ' << myints[1] << ' ' << myints[2] << '\n';

  return 0;
}